Не работает проксирование HTTPS трафика
У меня есть код:
import socket
from threading import Thread

class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, host, port, request_size_limit=4096):
        self.request_size_limit = request_size_limit

        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server_socket.bind((host, port))
        self.server_socket.listen()

        self.accept_connections()

    def accept_connections(self):
        while True:
            clsock, addr = self.server_socket.accept()
            user = UserHandler(self.request_size_limit)
            Thread(target=user.client_request, args=(clsock,)).start()

class UserHandler:
    def __init__(self, request_size_limit):
        self.request_size_limit = request_size_limit

    def client_request(self, client_socket):
        request = client_socket.recv(self.request_size_limit)
        if(request.decode().split(' ')[0] == 'CONNECT'):
            address = request.decode().split(' ')[1].split(':')[0]

            client_socket.send(b'HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n')
            request = client_socket.recv(self.request_size_limit)

            self.proxy_request(address, 443, request, client_socket)
        else:
            url = UserHandler.get_url(request)
            address, path = UserHandler.separate_url(url)
            request = UserHandler.prepare_request(request, address)

            self.proxy_request(address, 80, request, client_socket)

        client_socket.close()

    def proxy_request(self, remote_address, remote_port, request, client_socket, tls=False):
        remote_connect_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        remote_connect_socket.connect((remote_address, remote_port))

        remote_connect_socket.send(request)

        while True:
            read = remote_connect_socket.recv(self.request_size_limit)
            if len(read) == 0:
                break
            client_socket.send(read)

        remote_connect_socket.close()

    @staticmethod
    def get_url(request):
        return request.splitlines()[0].decode().split(' ')[1]

    @staticmethod
    def separate_url(url):
        splitted = url.split('/')
        return splitted[2], url.split(splitted[2])[1]

    @staticmethod
    def prepare_request(request, addr):
        request_lines = request.splitlines()
        request_line_split = request_lines[0].decode().split(' ')
        request_lines[0] = bytes(f'{request_line_split[0]} {request_line_split[1].split(addr)[1]} {request_line_split[2]}', encoding='UTF-8')
        return b'\r\n'.join(request_lines + [b''])

Proxy('0.0.0.0', 8008)

Проксирование обычного HTTP трафика работает отлично, но при попытке проксировании HTTPS браузер просто перестает загружать страницы, в чем проблема и как её исправить?
